# Variables not changing in For loop

Tags: c#, variables, loops

In my program I've defined some variables in "button1_Click" and also there is a "for" loop in "button1_Click" function. In that loop I want those variables to be changed, but they don't.
What should I be doing...passing them by reference? If yes, how?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double t=0;
            double x = double.Parse(X0.Text);
            double z = double.Parse(Z0.Text);
            double y = double.Parse(Y0.Text);
            double u = double.Parse(U0.Text);
            double tn = double.Parse(Tn.Text);
            double h = double.Parse(textbox_h.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < (tn / h); i++)
            {

                double K1x = h * fx(t, x, y, z, u);

                double K2x = h * fx(t + h / 2, x + K1x / 2, y + K1y / 2, z + K1z / 2, u + K1u / 2);

                double K3x = h * fx(t + h / 2, x + K2x / 2, y + K2y / 2, z + K2z / 2, u + K2u / 2);

                double K4x = h * fx(t + h, x + K3x, y + K3y, z + K3z, u + K3u);


                x =x+ (1 / 6)*(K1x + 2 * K2x + 2 * K3x + K4x);
                richTextBox1.Text += "X(" + (h * (i + 1)).ToString() + ")=" + x.ToString();


            }
```

All things are right but at the last line, new values of x doesn't go in x, and the old ones remain.
Note that fx, fz,fy,fu are functions that I've defined before.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. Why do you think x is not being updated? You may want to append a new line (Environment.NewLine) to richTextBox1.Text so you can see the values better.

Comment: shouldn't the richTextBox1.Text... line be outside of the for loop ? Cause it will be updated in the for loop, and you won't have time to see what's happening...

Comment: A lot better than your first attempt but you will need to document the expected and actual results better.

Comment: @ShellShock it wont change the rich box shows that!
I've checked it line bye line using f11 and foun that the problem is the last line, x doesn't change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `1 / 6` is `0`, because both `1` and `6` are `int`, so the result will also be an `int`. An `int` can't have any decimals, so they are simply dropped, there is no rounding happening. And `0.16666666...` without the decimals is `0`.

To fix it, make at least one of the two a double or float:

```
1.0 / 6
```

The complete line should now look like this:

```
x = x + (1.0 / 6)*(K1x + 2 * K2x + 2 * K3x + K4x);
```

Comment: Oh! really? could you please explain a little more?

Comment: I don't know what more I could explain here. If something is unclear, please ask specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your expression

```
1 / 6
```

That's an integer division and gives integer `0`. Consider using

```
1.0 / 6.0
```

instead.